# Revert to specific commit but can't push

Tags: git

I want to reset to a specific commit. I use the command `git reset --hard Head~5` This has reset my local. I make some changes and now I want to push. However I get `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`. I don't want to pull though otherwise I'm back to the most recent commit. How do I reset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can forcibly push but this is potentially problematic.

Are there other people working on this repo or is it just you? Are you absolutely sure you want to erase those commits from the remote?

`git push -f origin branch-name` will update the remote branch to match the changes you've just made.

But you need to take care when doing this. If you have colleagues working on the same branch you should tell them in case they have already pulled in those changes. Plus they may have pushed other changes which you'd be overriding.

Comment: Just me working on this branch. It's a small branch off the main dev branch.

Comment: In that case it will be safe to force push

Comment: And I'm correct that the `reset` and force push erases the commit history but a revert keeps it?

Comment: Yep that's right. The `revert` creates a new commit that inverts the changes of the commit that's being reverted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a `git push --force` (not always advisable, read below).

If you don't have permission to do a push force then it means you cannot reset commits, instead try [reverting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) them.

Note that if the branch is a main development branch, or it is already pulled by other developers, then resetting commits and pushing them (regardless of permission issues) is a dangerous thing to do, and `git revert` would be a better option.

This is the git revert equivalent of your example (`git reset --hard HEAD~5`):

```
git revert Head~5..HEAD
```

This will revert commits represented by `HEAD~4`, `HEAD~3`, ..., and `HEAD`. It will keep your existing commits, and then will add extra *revert commits* on top. There will be 1 revert commit per commit reverted which adds up to 5 revert commits in your case.

If you prefer to manage the commits yourself (e.g., revert them all in 1 commit instead of 5) use the `-n` option so that it will revert the changes in your local branch without committing them:

```
git revert -n Head~5..HEAD
```

Then it'll be up to you to commit the outstanding changes in your local branch.

`git reset` is safe when you're resetting local commits that are not yet pushed. If you have push force permission, and you're absolutely sure no one else has pulled the commit you are about to reset, you can reset them locally and then do a push force.

When it comes to commits already pushed, `git revert` is safer than `git reset` because you're not changing history, or removing commits already pulled and relied on by other team members. Note that if things get out of hand during reverting (e.g., you get a conflict that you're not sure how to resolve) you can always abort the operation by `git revert --abort`. For more information see the [git revert documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

Comment: How would I do a revert?